# Rails naming convention for "name" field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

If I have two models (let's say Employee and Event), should the field for their respective names be "employee_name" and "event_name" or should they simply both be called "name"?

Thanks

Comment: Just "name". It's easier to consume (duck-typing, etc).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

Not Required to call the respective name like employee_name etc.

Because We have a Unique Model like Employee If any entity in the model is belongs to this model So we did not make to it such like employee_name We can simply use name because we know what we are talking about.

Suppose If any model entity associated with any other model like event and they had any association of has_one , has_many etc.

Then in the corresponding model we need to specify the which model id we are talking about like employee_id in the event model.